# UWP. How to implement an in-app subscription?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, uwp

1. How to add in your universal app purchases subscriptions for a specific functionality? I.e. some features in the app would become available only when you purchase the subscription and for a certain period.
2. Whether the subscription is to act on all devices where you installed the program?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is all written in the documentation:
See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn532254.aspx) for how to implement in app purchases.

After a successfull purchase, set a `bool` in your `RoamingSettings` to true. Check for this to be true to enable the features.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx) for `RoamingSettings` documentation

Comment: I do not see anything about the subscription type of IAPs in the doc i.e. IAP that is billing the customer once a period automatically.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's correct. It would be more correct to say you can have timed purchases, which can be bought again after they expire